# Adjust colormap in holoviews bokeh to match distribution of values

Tags: colors, bokeh, color-mapping, holoviews

I have created a map in Holoviews in jupyter notebook with the bokeh extension using the following options:

```
%output size=150
%opts Overlay [show_legend=True, width=800 height=400]
%opts Points.Data [color_index='b' size_index='a' scaling_factor=10 colorbar=True](cmap='RdYlGn' size=3)
```

Both 'b' and 'a' are variables ranging between -1 and 1.

This produces two issues (also compare picture):

1. the points are sized according to the *absolute* value of variable 'a'. However, I'd like values to produce smaller (larger) points the more negative (positive) the value. Any solution to that (except for rescaling 'a' to a positive range before plotting)?
2. As there are significantly more positive values of 'b' than negative ones, almost all points a mapped to green color while the negative part of the color range gets very rarely used. I don't want to transform 'b', as there is meaning to its value which I would like to be displayed in the color legend. Any suggestions how to adjust the color map to reflect the distribution of 'b' values better?

I am new to holoviews/bokeh and not yet used to the syntax. Therefore I'd appreciate sample code as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question is quite straightforward, `Points` support a `size_fn` option which you can use to transform the size values before plotting something simple like offsetting the points by 1 would work. The second question is more tricky and there's no straightforward answer. If there are very few points below 0 I'd consider whether a diverging colormap is the right choice. Maybe just set the range of the color dimension to 0-1, use a standard colormap and set a special color for values outside the range.

```
# Make some fake data
lon, lat = np.random.rand(2, 100)*180-90
a = np.clip((np.random.randn(100) + 1)/2., -1, 1)
b = np.clip((np.random.randn(100) + 1)/2., -1, 1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'lon': lon, 'lat': lat, 'a': a, 'b': b})

gv.tile_sources.EsriImagery * gv.Points(df, ['lon', 'lat']).options(
    width=600, height=400, color_index='a', size_fn=lambda x: x+1, 
    scaling_factor=20, size_index='b', colorbar=True, cmap='Greens', 
    clipping_colors={'min': "red"}
).redim.range(a=(0, 1))
```

[image]

In the example above I used `size_fn` to offset the color values by one so they are all positive and can be scaled. Secondly I used the `.redim.range` method to set the range of color values from 0-1. Finally I used `clipping_colors` to say that any values lower than the min (of 0) should be colored red.

Answer (score 2):

To answer #2, you could make your own color map from a default color map and remove however many colors from the ends of the color map (changing start/stop) like this

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cmap_name = 'RdBu_r'
start = 0.4
stop = 1
n = 256
cmap = plt.get_cmap(cmap_name)
colors = cmap(np.linspace(start, stop, cmap.N))
new_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', colors=colors, N=n)
```

and then do a `points = points.redim.range(data=(-0.2, 1))`

As an example, below, I cut out all the blues from RdBu_r, leaving only reds
https://holoext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/changing_colorbar_cmap.html#Colorbar-string-shortcut